# MySQL error while create databaseon mariadb

Tags: virtualbox, mysql, mariadb, cacti

Trying new adventures, been set up cacti on my VirtualBox Machine, sticking to vary instructions, exploring my problem I stuck in, but can't go further.

I'm doing alright till I'm creating database on mariadb:

`sudo mysql -u root -p mysql < /usr/share/mysql/mysql_test_data_timezone.sql`

Then error appears everytime:

`ERROR 1062 (23000) at line 18: Duplicate entry 'MET' for key 'PRIMARY'`

Values ubuntu complaining for in 18th string in my file are:

`INSERT INTO time_zone_name (Name, Time_Zone_id) Values ('MET', 1), ('UTC', 2), ('Universal', 2), ('Europe/Moscow', 3) etc`

What am I doing wrong?

Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS

mysql Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.6.11-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using Editline wrapper

Didn't find VMBox version

docdroid.net/jP70dUw/install-cacti-step-by-step-txt

doing all according this link –

Comment: The script is trying to insert data into the `time_zone_name` table and almost certainly the table already contains data. Do a `select * from time_zone_name` and see. Also, you don't need to post multiple comments on your own post unless replying to comments. Just edit your original post.

Comment: @codlord do you mean I should manually set it? script you gave, where I'm writing it down to?

Comment: Connect to your database `sudo mysql -u root -p mysql` and then issue select statements such as `select * from time_zone_name;` If the tables already have the same data in as the script `/usr/share/mysql/mysql_test_data_timezone.sql` then there is no need to run the script.